# How to query for an entry that falls between start and end date - DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am new to DynamoDB, and had a question how I can find all of the live entries in my DynamoDb table.  Each entry in my table has a start and end date.  I am confused on how I can query for the entries that the current date falls between the start and end date.  Any ideas how I can do this?

I understand that I can only have a primary and range key. Is it possible to query for other columns in the entry?

Each entry looks like this:

id: xxxxxx
startDate: 123456 // Epoch time
endDate: 334243 // Epoch time

Comment: Do you know the `id` you want to query against? If not, you will have to use a `Scan`.

Comment: @mkobit In my case, I have a partition key value available, for example 'Cat1', the name of a category. How to model data and how to query, if I have to query all categories between a start date and end date ? Presently, I put start date and enddate  together in Sort Key, for example 1563840000-1565654399 ie separated by -. How to query this ? I want to post a question on this, but it would be similar to this question, Please atleast let me know how to  draft a proper new question based on my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know the hashkey of your item(looks like 'id' in your case) then the only way to query DynamoDB is using a full table scan.

You can do a table scan using multiple conditions, but this is inefficient.

Comment: I do have a partition key value, since I am using a GSI, could you please tell the best way to query for a records  start date and end  date ?

Answer (score -3):

First you'll need to establish current epoch time. Then you can look to see if current epoch falls between your start and end epoch times. Most SQL variants have a `BETWEEN(now, start, end)` function. If not, then you'd look for `now >= start AND now <= end`. And yes, you can return any column in your query.

Comment: How is this related to DynamoDB?

Comment: It's not. It could be any DB. The question is about how to query within a date range, which I answered. Please undo your click.